# How can use a large (mora than 1500 characters) SSML speech file into aws sumerian with amazon polly?

Tags: ssml, amazon-polly, amazon-sumerian

I´m working in AWS sumerian and I use a host to speech my ssml file. When I use more than 1500 characters the scene can not run and I receive a message error that the max lengh has reached.

I want need to use a ssml speech file with more than 5000 characters, so if someone know how to split a large speech file in sumerian and then play it with amazon polly, please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What if you just split the files and sequence them in the state machine?